# Expand and collapse table row with values from database php

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that expand and collapse its table row. Im trying to display my database values in it. However, only the first row expands and displays the value of the row req. The other rows are not expanding and not showing its value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').find('tr:gt(0)').hide();;
  $('#heading').addClass('hCollapsed');


  $("#heading").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().toggle();
    if ($(this).hasClass('hCollapsed')) {
      $(this).removeClass('hCollapsed').addClass('hExpanded');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('hExpanded').addClass('hCollapsed');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.hCollapsed::before {
  content: "+ ";
}

.hExpanded::before {
  content: "- ";
}

#heading {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>

<?php   
 $info= "SELECT slider_issue.issue, slider_requirement.req FROM slider_issue
 INNER JOIN slider_requirement ON slider_issue.issue_id = slider_requirement.req_id";
 
  $queryres= mysqli_query($conn,$info);
  while ($rowwaf= mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryres))
  {
echo " 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id=\"heading\" colspan=\"2\"><b>".$rowwaf["issue"]."</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>".$rowwaf["req"]."</td>
  </tr>
</table>
";
  }
?>
        
</body>
```

Comment: 1. remove PHP from tte equation. 2. Make this code work with clear HTML/JS. 3. Rebuild this HTML/JS from PHP, having the clean version as a blueprint

Comment: IM sorry I have no idea on how to start.

Comment: *So I told you* exactly how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using heading as Id, so your code is working for first row only because Id is unique on page, change it to class and you will get output as you expected.
Please check your updated code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').find('tr:gt(0)').hide();;
  $('.heading').addClass('hCollapsed');


  $(".heading").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().toggle();
    if ($(this).hasClass('hCollapsed')) {
      $(this).removeClass('hCollapsed').addClass('hExpanded');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('hExpanded').addClass('hCollapsed');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.hCollapsed::before {
  content: "+ ";
}

.hExpanded::before {
  content: "- ";
}

.heading {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>

<?php   
 $info= "SELECT slider_issue.issue, slider_requirement.req FROM slider_issue
 INNER JOIN slider_requirement ON slider_issue.issue_id = slider_requirement.req_id";
 
  $queryres= mysqli_query($conn,$info);
  while ($rowwaf= mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryres))
  {
echo " 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=\"heading\" colspan=\"2\"><b>".$rowwaf["issue"]."</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>".$rowwaf["req"]."</td>
  </tr>
</table>
";
  }
?>
        
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Working perfectly